# A Optimization problem using co-ordinates of joint numerical range.

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

Let $\mathbf{A}_1,\dots,\mathbf{A}_L$ be $N\times N$ hermitian matrices. Define the mapping from the $N-$dimensional unit sphere to $\mathbb{R}^L$ as 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}=\{\left(\mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{A}_1\mathbf{u},\dots,\mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{A}_L\mathbf{u}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^L\mid \mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{u}=1\}
\end{align} 
$\mathcal{S}$ is defined as the joint numerical range of matrices $\mathbf{A}_i$. Let $\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{S}$, so that $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\dots,x_L]^T$ is a $L\times 1$ real vector and $x_i=\mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{A}_i\mathbf{u}$ for some $\mathbf{u}$ from unit sphere. Consider the optimization problem
\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{S}}~&f_0(\mathbf{x}) \\
\text{subject to}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~&~~f_k(\mathbf{x})\leq 0,~~k=1,\dots,K
\end{align}
where all $f_0(.),\dots,f_K(.)$ are affine functions of $\mathbf{x}$.

Is this a convex optimization problem? How do I approach it? Actually, I would like to address the more complicated case where $f_k(.)$ are all convex functions of $\mathbf{x}$. However any direction in this regard is also fine?

Comment: This paper may be of your interest: http://www.resnet.wm.edu/~cklixx/poon-1.pdf

Comment: No, this is not a convex optimization problem in general, since the joint numerical range is not convex in general. Optimization problems of this form are NP-hard in general.

In your problem, does it make sense to just explicitly optimize over the convex hull of $\mathcal{S}$ instead of $\mathcal{S}$ itself? That would turn this into a convex optimization problem (even a semidefinite program), which can be solved easily.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston  Yes, I would like to see that.

Comment: The convex hull of $\mathcal{S}$ is the set $\{ (\mathrm{Tr}(A_1\rho),\ldots,\mathrm{Tr}(A_L\rho) | \mathrm{Tr}(\rho) = 1, \rho \geq 0\}$ (where by $\rho \geq 0$ I mean that $\rho$ is positive semidefinite). You can perform the optimization over this set using semidefinite programming (for example, if you download the [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) toolbox for MATLAB, you can type the problem in MATLAB almost exactly as it is written here and it will solve it).

Comment: So in that case, we have to adopt a relaxation, is it? How can we solve it if we can assume $\mathcal{S}$ is convex.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston can you help with the case where I can assume $\mathcal{S}$ is convex?